# Mongodb Realm Flexible Sync not syncing to server on an Android app

Tags: android, mongodb, realm

I generated a simple todo app using the realm sync template with everything at the default.

And then I setup my Android app like this:

*build.gradle*

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:10.11.1'
    }
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.0' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.10' apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt" version "1.6.20" apply false
}
```

*app/build.gradle*

```
plugins {
    ...
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt'
    id 'realm-android'
}

android {
    ...

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            buildConfigField "String", "RealmAppId", '"*****"'
        }
        release {
            buildConfigField "String", "RealmAppId", '"*****"'
            ...
        }
    }
    ...
    
    realm {
        syncEnabled = true
    }
}
```

*App.kt*

```
class App : Application() {
    val realmSync by lazy {
        App(BuildConfig.RealmAppId)
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        Realm.init(this)
    }
}
```

*Item.kt*

```
open class Item : RealmObject() {
    @PrimaryKey
    @RealmField("_id")
    var id: ObjectId = ObjectId()
    var isComplete: Boolean = false
    var summary: String = ""

    @RealmField("owner_id")
    var ownerId: String = ""
}
```

*MainActivity.kt*

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var realm: Realm
    private lateinit var user: User

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        login()

        binding.button.setOnClickListener { add() }
    }

    private fun login() {
        val app = (application as App).realmSync
        app.loginAsync(Credentials.anonymous()) {
            if (it.isSuccess) {
                user = it.get()
                setupRealm()
            } else {
                println("__print::Error:${it.error.errorMessage}")
            }
        }
    }

    private fun setupRealm() {
        val config = SyncConfiguration.defaultConfig(user)
        realm = Realm.getInstance(config)
        realm.addChangeListener {
            updateUi()
        }
        subscribe()
    }

    private fun subscribe() {
        realm.subscriptions.update {
            val sub = Subscription.create(
                "todos",
                realm.where(Item::class.java)
            )
            it.addOrUpdate(sub)
        }

        updateUi()
    }

    private fun updateUi() {
        val items = realm.where(Item::class.java).findAll()
        println("__print::ITEMS::$items")
    }

    private fun add() {
        val item = Item()
        item.ownerId = user.id
        item.summary = java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString()
        realm.executeTransactionAsync {
            it.insert(item)
        }
    }
}
```

*Output::*

```
__print::ITEMS::[Item = proxy[{id:637dc4e39caf9a0fd073996f},{isComplete:false},{summary:},{ownerId:637dc4da72f7f15c96d70cb1}], Item = proxy[{id:637dc4e59caf9a0fd0739970},{isComplete:false},{summary:},{ownerId:637dc4da72f7f15c96d70cb1}]]
```

The data is being created and persisted but it's not syncing to the server. Can someone point me where am missing it?

Comment: That's quite a bit of code for us to parse though - in general the best questions have a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Did you verify the server info via the Realm Console is set up correctly? Also, please check your app logs to see if there are any errors. Update your question with that info and reduce your code and we'll take a look!

Comment: Thanks @Jay, fixed it the issue was with data not matching the schema, since I didn't activate Dev Mode.

Comment: Wonderful! Glad I could help. Good luck with your project.